# Distance between two farthest points in a raster

Tags: r, raster, euclidean-distance

I have a geographical area as a raster file and I want to recover the longest distance that can be between the raster cells locations. In another word, the longest trajectory. (the location is represented by the center of the cell). Is it possible to do in R?

Comment: Please add a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Thank you

Comment: @ava I just want to calculate the maximal distance between any two cells in the raster object but I don't know how to do It.

Comment: What you want is not that clear ("any two cells", or "farthest points"?). Please be very specific. And please add a *minimal, self-contained, reproducible example*  ---- just like in the R help files; to illustrate what you are after.

Comment: @RobertHijmans I edited my post I don't know if it's clearer now.

Comment: It is very vague. A raster has many cells. Which cells. Please include an example like `r <- raster(ncol=10, nrow=10)` etc, and then use that to explain *exactly* what you want to do and what the answer should be.

Comment: I want to recover only the distance between the two farthest cells in the raster that are not NA.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the risk of wasting time because there is no reproducible example to check what is required and whether the answer is correct, here is some R code to do what I think is required. Basically, find the edge of a raster because the maximum distances will involve the edges. From there, find the distances between all pairs of edge points to determine the maximum distance globally.

```
library(raster)
library(rgdal)
library(rgeos)

# A reproducible raster file
f <- system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster")
r <- raster(f)
    
# Find the edge of the raster values
b <- boundaries(r)
b[b==0] <- NA
b <- trim(b)
    
# Find the distances between pairs of points 
# using the suggestion from the comments
# so that lon lat data would also work
gd <- pointDistance(rasterToPoints(b)[,1:2], lonlat=FALSE)

# Make a data frame
df <- data.frame(rasterToPoints(b))

# Find the maximum row and column and the points these correspond to
maxpair <- which(gd==max(gd), arr.ind=T)
firstpoint <- df[maxpair[1],]
secondpoint <- df[maxpair[2],]
    
# Plot things
plot(r)
points(firstpoint, col='red', cex=4, pch=10)
points(secondpoint, col='red', cex=4, pch=10)
```

[image]

Comment: Very nice. I would use `gd <- pointDistance(rasterToPoints(b)[,1:2], lonlat=FALSE)` such that it can be adapted to lonlat data.

Comment: @RobertHijmans - good suggestion. I've changed my answer to reflect it.